# Evaluation of $\int\frac{1}{\sin^2 x+\sin x+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sin^2 x+\sin x+1}dx$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Using $$\; \bullet\;  x^2+x+1 = (x-\omega)\cdot (x-\omega^2)\;,$$ where $\omega,\omega^2$ are cube root of unity

So we can write Integal $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{(\sin x-\omega)\cdot (\sin x-\omega^2)}dx$$

So we get  $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{\omega-\omega^2}\int\frac{(\sin x-\omega^2)-(\sin x-\omega)}{(\sin x-\omega)\cdot (\sin x-\omega^2)}dx$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{\omega-\omega^2}\int \left[\frac{1}{\sin x-\omega}-\frac{1}{\sin x-\omega^2}\right]dx$$

Now Substitute $$\displaystyle \sin x= \frac{2\tan \frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}$$

Can we solve it above method our we directly put $$\displaystyle \sin x= \frac{2\tan \frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}$$

in $$\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sin^2 x+\sin x+1}dx$$ and then solve it.

Or is there is any other process by which we can solve it.

Help me , Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Substitute $\sin x=\frac{1-y^2}{1+y^2}$, or $y=\sec x - \tan x$
\begin{align}
&\int \frac{1}{\sin^2 x+\sin x+1}dx\\
=&-\int\frac{2+{2y^2}}{3+y^4}dy
= -\int\frac{\frac2{y^2}+{2}}{\frac3{y^2}+y^2}dy \\
=&\ \frac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt{6\sqrt3}}\tan^{-1}\frac{y-{\sqrt3}y^{-1}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt3}}
-\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt{6\sqrt3}}\coth^{-1}\frac{y+{\sqrt3}y^{-1}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt3}}\\
= &\ \frac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt{6\sqrt3}}\tan^{-1}\frac{(\sqrt3-1)\sec x+(\sqrt3+1)\tan x}{\sqrt{2\sqrt3}}\\
&+\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt{6\sqrt3}}\coth^{-1}\frac{(\sqrt3+1)\sec x+(\sqrt3-1)\tan x}{\sqrt{2\sqrt3}}+C\\
\end{align}
which leads to the definite integral below
\begin{align}
 &\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2} \frac{dx}{\sin^2 x+\sin x+1}
=\frac\pi3 \sqrt{3+2\sqrt3}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

By using Weierstrass substitution $x=2\arctan t$ the problem boils down to computing
$$ \int\frac{1+t^2}{1+2t+6t^2+2t^3+t^4}\,dt $$
through partial fraction decomposition. The roots of that palyndromic $4$th-degree polynomial are located at $t=-\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(-3\pm i \sqrt{3}\right)}$. The remaining part is just tedious work.

Comment: I think the tedious work yields $${\frac {\sqrt {-6-2\,i\sqrt {3}}}{6}\ln  \left( -i\sqrt {3}+\sqrt {-6-
2\,i\sqrt {3}}+2\,\tan \left( x/2 \right) +1 \right) }-{\frac {\sqrt {
-6-2\,i\sqrt {3}}}{6}\ln  \left( -i\sqrt {3}-\sqrt {-6-2\,i\sqrt {3}}+
2\,\tan \left( x/2 \right) +1 \right) }-{\frac {\sqrt {-6+2\,i\sqrt {3
}}}{6}\ln  \left( i\sqrt {3}+2\,\tan \left( x/2 \right) -\sqrt {-6+2\,
i\sqrt {3}}+1 \right) }+{\frac {\sqrt {-6+2\,i\sqrt {3}}}{6}\ln 
 \left( i\sqrt {3}+2\,\tan \left( x/2 \right) +\sqrt {-6+2\,i\sqrt {3}
}+1 \right) }$$